# Angular CLI component generation error for component names like 'com2'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

Using Angular CLI version 8.3.26 on windows 10 OS on a newly created project with

```
ng new project-name
```

I have tried to generate a component with command :

```
ng g component com2
```

and i have got error

> 'file '\.\com2' can not be opened. folder '\.\' does not exists.

everything goes well when trying another component name like 'comtwo' or 'component2' but any name like 'com2' or 'com3' fails.

Comment: there is no rule to prevent component whose name is com2

Comment: @Çağrı : this restriction is related to windows OS. it doesn't let creating folder with name 'com1', 'com2',  ...
refference : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-rename-a-folder-to-com-errorthe/ff48c793-ab97-4881-952a-df195321c11c

Comment: No I just tried to add this component names. And I added

Comment: @Çağrı : please check the link. its an OS rule from MS-DOS to Windows. try creating a folder with name 'com2' on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem :

Any folder name like 'com1', 'com2' , .... ('com#') is forbidden on windows OS.

Comment: refference : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-rename-a-folder-to-com-errorthe/ff48c793-ab97-4881-952a-df195321c11c